# how to show my DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a one dropdown menu so when I click on first item, I want to show DIV id=city3. and while I select another item, It will show DIV id=km automatically.

Problem : While I select first item, Div id=city3 is not visible and while I select another item, Div id=km is visible. So I want to show div id=city3 while I select first item.

Here is code.

```
$("#city_to").change(function()
{
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    if(id==1)
    {
         $("#city3").show();
         $(".km").hide();
         $(".distance").val('');
         $(".allowance1").val('');
         $(".hq_allowance1").val('');
         $(".exhq_allowance1").val('');
         $(".os_allowance1").val('');
         $(".total_allowance").val('');
         $(".total").val('');
    }
    else
    {   
        $(".km").show();
        $("#city3").hide();

        $(".allowance").val('');
        $(".hq_allowance").val('');
        $(".exhq_allowance").val('');
        $(".os_allowance").val('');
        $(".total_allowance1").val('');
        $(".total").val('');

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_pages/km.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".km").html(html);
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure about the `id` ? it looks like you don't get into the `if`, but in the `else`... Try to var_dump the value of `id`

Comment: `console.log(id)` your `id` :)

Comment: BTW, the second block shows `class=km`, not `id=km`.

Comment: I found out my solution. Thank You.

Comment: And the solution is ?

Comment: I used some conditions so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my example so you can understand the working process.

[**DEMO WORK**](https://jsfiddle.net/tapos00/jf9nrr4y/)

```
<ul>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc1">Home</li>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc2">about</li>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc3">serive</li>
    <li class="abc" data-id="abc4">contact</li>
</ul>
<div class="mm" id="abc1">Home worlld</div>
<div class="mm" id="abc2">about worlld</div>
<div class="mm" id="abc3">Service worlld</div>
<div class="mm" id="abc4">Contact worlld</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mm").hide();
    $(".abc").click(function(){
          var mm = $(this).data("id");
            $(".mm").hide();
            $("#"+mm).show();
      });
});
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to link it to what is asked, can you at least add a condition about "abc1" to show/hide 2 different divs ?

Comment: why you need condition at first hide all the div then get the value from data-id attribute then show this specific id show

Comment: It isin't asked to show a div for each item of the dropdown. It is asked to show a div when you select the first, and a diffrent one for all others (including an ajax call, so very specific behavior)...

Comment: I found out my solution. Thank You.